# Access to OpenStreetMap is "forbidden" on my work's internet connection

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, basemap

When I use QGIS at work and have an Open Street Map layer, I get the Layer Error "Access denied: Forbidden." The Layer actually works ok, until I zoom in enough, and the prompt "**OpenStreetMap:** Access Denied: Forbidden" never leaves.
We're a small team at work and so don't have an IT team or anyone to turn to among the staff to diagnose the issue. I know it's an issue with the ISP blocking the URL or putting restrictions on the domain, but I don't know what exactly is being blocked.

Has anyone had this issue before and know what exactly to say to our ISP?

Comment: How do you connect to the internet? Is it via a VPN? Can you access the address for OpenStreet maps using a browser outside your organisation's connection?

Comment: @KeaganAllan
As far as I can tell there's no VPN at work, it's just blocked through their ISP.
And when I connect through my mobile data using Hotspot, or on my home WiFi on days I Work From Home, I can access OpenStreetMap easily.